# Django, ajax and HttpOnly cookies

Tags: cookies, csrf, ajax, django

While reading "Tangled web" I came across description of http only cookies and I wanted to try it out in my project, so I've added these settings according according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly):

```
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

And went to console to dive into it. As expected no csrf token or session cookie showed up when I executed some JS:

```
> document.cookie
"djdt=hide"
```

However, I have AJAX running in background polling some data from the server beginning with:

```
function doPoll() {
    $.get(predefinedUrl){
        (...)
```

And it seems that somehow it has access to this data:
[image: screenshot of request cookie headers].

My questions are: how is this data accessible? Is it enough that this script makes request to my site and browser handles the rest (like it does in "regular" cases)? Does it mean I should be able to securely switch on this http only flag by default and not worry that frontend scripts will not be able to make requests? Is there anything I should pay attention for?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that the script has access to the `httpOnly` cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is this data accessible?

It's not. If your browser issues a request, including AJAX requests, it will include all cookies for the target domain in the `Cookie` header, even `httpOnly` cookies.<sup>1</sup> However, your script can't access them since the headers `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie` are [forbidden headers per specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name) and you can't extract them with, say, `XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')`.

> Does it mean I should be able to securely switch on this http only flag by default and not worry that frontend scripts will not be able to make requests?

With `httpOnly` cookies your script can still make authenticated requests, it just can't read the values of the `httpOnly` cookies which are sent along. Turning on `httpOnly` only breaks functionality if you explicitly handle the cookies on the client side.

<sup>1</sup> `sameSite` cookies can be an exception.